# scp output from remote grep back to my machine in a script

Tags: bash, ssh, scp

I am trying to write a script that would use a ssh session to do a grep on a huge logfile, cat the ouput to a temp file and scp the temp file back to the client machine:

```
ssh user@server  grep pattern logfile.log | cat > temp.txt
scp user@server:/temp.txt .
```

What is the best way to write such a action in a script?

Comment: Why not `ssh user@server grep pattern logfile.log >temp.txt`? Unless there's a reason to leave`temp.txt` on the server. Also `scp user@server:/temp.txt .` is probably wrong, use `scp user@server:temp.txt .` instead.

Comment: i was not aware this would be possible without creating a file on the remote server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do this in one step:

```
ssh user@server "grep pattern logfile.log" > temp.txt
```

This will `ssh` to the remote host, issue `grep pattern logfile.log` on that remote host and
redirect the output of the whole `ssh` command to your ***local*** file `temp.txt`.

In this case quoting matters a lot, i.e. it's crucial where you put the quotes `"`. For instance

```
ssh user@server "grep pattern logfile.log > temp.txt"
```

would write the output to a file on the ***remote*** host (not what you want) because it 
runs the complete `"grep pattern logfile.log > temp.txt"` on that host. But in the first case
only the command is run remotely and the redirection happens on your local host.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you don't need to pipe the command to `cat`, just redirect it:

```
grep pattern logfile > mylog.log
```

Also the `temp.txt` will be created on your machine and not the server, to create it on server you have to quote the command:

```
ssh user@server "grep pattern logfile | whatever > temp.log"
```

I would go with:

```
ssh user@server grep pattern logfile.txt > mylog.log
```

It would run `grep pattern` on `logfile.txt` then creates `mylog.log` on my machine.